# Selenium Grid 4. how to target and run test on specific node?

Tags: java, selenium, e2e-testing, selenium-grid

I'm new to Selenium Grid 4 and trying to setting up the grid with Node & Hub Mode and run the test.Below is my setup;

- Hub: Linux
- Node A: MacOS with Chrome, Edge, Safari, Firefox installed
- Node B: Windows10 with Chrome, Edge, Firefox installed.

Both node are successfully registered to the hub and also hub status also indicates that it's ready.

What I want to achieve is that I want to be able to select specific node to run test on the browser of my choice.

For example, I want to run my test with Chrome browser running on Node A(MacOS machine) but not Node B(Windows machine). To achieve this, what I've tried is that I've set platform value to the WebDriver object and browser as the code below:

```
     WebDriver driver;
     DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
     capability.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
     driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://Hub-address:4444"), capability);
```

However, I got an error

```
   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session for <CreateSessionRequest with Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platform: MAC, version: }>
```

If I get rid of '***capability.setPlatform(Platform.MAC)***;` part, it will always run on Node B(Windows machine)

I've been searching on the net to achieve this but most of articles and references are based on selenium gird 3 or older, couldn't get any help. Also I've tried with nodeconfig.json file from Grid 3 but no luck....

is there any way to achieve this??

Comment: You have issue in your node pc..Install driver and browser correctly with correct version

Comment: I've double checked the settings (driver, version etc..) on node pc and all the nodes has the same version of Grid, and browsers and drivers are correctly installed on those node since the nodes are working fine if tested separately. Current issue is happens when those two node are connected to the hub.